# Protractor: uploading images don't work in chrome headless mode

Tags: protractor, google-chrome-headless

I try to upload files and it works with regular Chrome, but doesn't work with Chrome headless mode.
I use protractor 5.4.1 to test Angular 7.0.2

protractor.base.conf.js:

```
chrome_HL: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: [
            '--disable-browser-side-navigation',
            '--headless',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-extensions',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--window-size=1900,1400'
        ],
    }
}
```

spec.ts:

```
describe('Test', () => {
    const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    it('Upload files', async (done) => {
        let fileToUpload = '../../files-to-upload/image1.jpeg',
            absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
        element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
        uploadedImage = element.all(by.css('.image'))
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(uploadedImage.get(0)), 5000, 'Image is not present on the page');  
        done();  
    });
});
```